# How to use USQL database project that has credentials?

Tags: azure, u-sql

Since CREATE CREDENTIAL is deprecated, and the new project type outputs .usqldbpack to be run with PackageDeploymentTool.exe, how do we handle external SQL database sources and credentials?

Database don't exists yet, so can't run. PowerShell to create credential on it.

Previously I handled this by running a PowerShell script that made the DB and schema, then ran PS to create credential, and then continued to create the rest of the analytics db.

Any suggestions? Should credentials instead be placed on master?